# Plotting GPX onto Basemap

Tags: matlab, gpx

I'm trying to plot GPX data using the geoshow function in MATLAB. Ideally, I want to be able to select the GPX file from a file explorer, which is why I used the uigetfile function.

What I get from my current code is the full plot of data (lats/longs) with the correct axes. However, I'm having a tough time getting this data overlayed onto a map.

I've tried using the webmap functions but this is not exactly what my team envisions due to the extremely limited access to the Internet (in which we would be pulling public map servers from.) I'm constrained to just very simple maps, which is fine!

This is the code that I first proposed that does exactly what I want in terms of functionality. Plot a path from start to finish on top of a physical map:

```
% Window prompt to retrieve file. %
GetFile = uigetfile('','Select a file.');
% Read GPX file. %
GPXFile = gpxread(GetFile, 'FeatureType', 'track');

% Retrieve Latitude & Longitudal data from GPX file. %
Lat = GPXFile.Latitude;
Lon = GPXFile.Longitude;

% Base map. %

webmap('World Imag');
colors = {'red'};
wmline(GPXFile, 'Color', colors);
wmzoom(10)
webmap('World Topographic Map');
colors = {'red'};
wmline(GPXFile, 'Color', colors);
wmzoom(10)
```

After proposal, I have "dumbed" it down to this:

```
clc; clear;

% Select file
GetFile = uigetfile('','Select a file.');
% Read data from a GPX file. 
trk = gpxread(GetFile, 'FeatureType', 'track');

% Establish Lat/Lon from data
Lat = trk.Latitude;
Lon = trk.Longitude;

% Line plot from data 
geoshow(Lat, Lon, 'LineWidth', 2)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get this data onto a map.

Again, I'm expecting to get a path onto a specific map region depending on where the longitude and latitude is. I'd like for the longs/lats to dictate where my axes are on the map.

Comment: Can you provide your sampledata? https://filebin.net/

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/gpx/ 
I used this GPX file offered for download.